# Windows cmd scrambles things when running "adb pull [target] [destination]" inside a FOR loop

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, adb

I am trying to create a batch file that pulls all my dashcam videos from my Android phone using *adb pull*.

```
set source=/mnt/m_external_sd/Android/data/com.happyconz.blackbox/files/autoboy/autoboy_video
set destination=S:\Archive\Autoboy\original
for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`adb shell ls %source%`) do (
    echo.adb pull %source%/%%f
)
```

This script **works**, as this creates the following output (echoing for debugging purposes):

> adb pull /mnt/m_external_sd/Android/data/com.happyconz.blackbox/files/autoboy/autoboy_video/2017_08_28_08_33_53.mp4
>
> adb pull /mnt/m_external_sd/Android/data/com.happyconz.blackbox/files/autoboy/autoboy_video/2017_08_28_18_35_14.mp4
>
> *[...]*

---

However, when I try to define a destination to the *adb pull* command, it **does not work**.

```
set source=/mnt/m_external_sd/Android/data/com.happyconz.blackbox/files/autoboy/autoboy_video
set destination=S:\Archive\Autoboy\original
for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`adb shell ls %source%`) do (
    echo.adb pull %source%/%%f %destination%\%%f
)
```

This one gives the following output:

> S:\Archive\Autoboy\original\2017_08_28_08_33_53.mp4nz.blackbox/files/autoboy/autoboy_video/2017_08_28_08_33_53.mp4
>
> S:\Archive\Autoboy\original\2017_08_28_18_35_14.mp4nz.blackbox/files/autoboy/autoboy_video/2017_08_28_18_35_14.mp4
>
> *[...]*

---

If I try to actually run the command instead of echoing, it gives me a different scrambled string:

> ' does not existmnt/m_external_sd/Android/data/com.happyconz.blackbox/files/autoboy/autoboy_video/2017_08_28_08_33_53.mp4

---

Is there something I need to set in cmd before running this script, or is this a real bug?

Of course I can *cd* into my dest. dir, then running the pull without giving it the destination, but that is an unnecessary complication to a simple script.

<sub>I bet it is because Windows and Unix use different *new line* definitions.</sub>

Comment: Save the output of adb pull into a file:  `adb shell ls %source% > output.txt`   and check it for carriage returns (CR). Something is wrong with them.

Answer (score 0):

Change your final filename to use only the base and extension of the file, and quote-encapsulate it for safety:

```
echo.adb pull %source%/%%f "%destination%\%%~nxf"
```

That is likely to help.